# Stack of integers in C

Tags: c, stack

I'm learning C, and currently I follows `C99` standard. Here is my implementation of integer-stack, which is just a stack you can do: push, pop, and print the content of the stack.

Here are some problems I currently have:

1. Is that `#define STACK_MAX 1000` a good idea? Should I consider make it configurable in runtime?
2. It's impossible to make `struct int_stack *` to `int_stack *`, like C++, right?

Other than these two problem, I need feedbacks about anything you think important, but I missed out, thank you.

---

**int_stack.h**:

```
#ifndef INT_STACK_H
#define INT_STACK_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define STACK_MAX 1000


typedef struct int_stack {
    int top;
    int data[STACK_MAX];

    bool (*push)(struct int_stack *, int);
    bool (*pop)(struct int_stack *, int *);
    int (*size)(struct int_stack *);
    void (*print_stack)(struct int_stack *);

} int_stack;

bool push(int_stack *self, int item) {
    if (self->top == STACK_MAX)
        return false;
    self->data[self->top++] = item;
    return true;
}

bool pop(int_stack *self, int *out) {
    if (size(self) == 0)
        return false;
    *out = self->data[--self->top];
    return true;
}

int size(int_stack *self) {
    return self->top;
}

void print_stack(int_stack *self) {
    printf("| top |\n");
    for (int i = self->top-1; i >= 0; i--)
        printf("| %3d |\n", self->data[i]);
}

void array_zeros_init(int A[], int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        A[i] = 0;
}

void stack_init(struct int_stack *stack) {
    stack->top = 0;
    array_zeros_init(stack->data, STACK_MAX);
    stack->push = &push;
    stack->pop = &pop;
    stack->size = &size;
    stack->print_stack = &print_stack;
}

#endif // !INT_STACK_H
```

Comment: Maybe make your function pointers static ? I don’t know much about c though, more of a c++ guy...

Answer (score 1):

We wouldn't normally put the function definitions in the header like that.  Just write the *declarations* that are needed by the calling code, and put the definitions into their own source file.

It seems odd to have these function pointers:

> ```
> bool (*push)(struct int_stack *, int);
> bool (*pop)(struct int_stack *, int *);
> int (*size)(struct int_stack *);
> void (*print_stack)(struct int_stack *);
> ```

Nothing needs them, so just omit them.

`pop()` uses `size()` before the latter is defined.  We could solve this by re-ordering, but separating declarations from definitions will naturally fix this.

`size()` and `print()` don't need to modify the stack, so they should accept pointer to const object.

The function names are all vulnerable to collisions.  I'd suggest adding a common prefix to distinguish and group them.

Writing zeros to the unused elements is a bit pointless, as those elements are not reachable through the public interface.

Here's my re-write:

#### Header:

```
#ifndef INT_STACK_H
#define INT_STACK_H

#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct int_stack int_stack;

int_stack *stack_create(void);
void stack_free(int_stack *self);

bool stack_push(int_stack *self, int item);
bool stack_pop(int_stack *self, int *out);
int stack_size(const int_stack *self);
void stack_print(const int_stack *self);

#endif // !INT_STACK_H
```

#### Implementation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define STACK_MAX 1000

struct int_stack {
    int top;
    int data[STACK_MAX];
};


int_stack *stack_create(void) {
    int_stack *stack = malloc(sizeof *stack);
    if (stack) {
        stack->top = 0;
    }
    return stack;
}

void stack_free(int_stack *self) {
    free(self);
}

bool stack_push(int_stack *self, int item) {
    if (self->top == STACK_MAX) {
        return false;
    }
    self->data[self->top++] = item;
    return true;
}

bool stack_pop(int_stack *self, int *out) {
    if (stack_size(self) == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    *out = self->data[--self->top];
    return true;
}

int stack_size(const int_stack *self) {
    return self->top;
}

void stack_print(const int_stack *self) {
    printf("| top |\n");
    for (int i = self->top-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        printf("| %3d |\n", self->data[i]);
    }
}
```